# js best practice to name class methods/properties of an extendable class

Tags: javascript, typescript, getter-setter

I am writing a package that provides an abstract class that will later be extended by the users. I want to avoid any naming conflicts between the base class properties/methods and the ones assigned by the users. Specifically, I have the properties collection and schema:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    collection
    schema
}
```

This way it is not unlikely that the extending class will also implement those properties, but with another purpose (i.e. they are not supposed to be overrides).

Option A, prefixwith _:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    _collection
    _schema
}
```

Now it is a lot less likely the there will be name collisions. But I don't really like the _

Option B, prefix with _ but expose through methods:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    _collection
    _schema

    getCollection() { return this._collection }
    setCollection(collection) { this._collection = collection }
    ...
}
```

I prefer it to A, but it seems a little "oldschool" since I would normally rather use getters setters:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    _collection
    _schema

    get collection() { return this._collection }
    set collection(collection) { this._collection = collection }
    ...
}
```

but this way I am back to the naming problem.

So what are commonly used solutions for building a 3rd party package?

Answer (score 0):

> it is not unlikely that the extending class will also implement those properties, but with another purpose

No. Anyone extending your abstract class will know its public properties and not override them. If they do, it's their problem not yours; this is nothing you can guard against.

If you want to use "private" properties (to be used in the public methods of your class) that cannot collide with properties defined by the subclasses, ES6 symbols are the way to go.